# How can I avoud tag soup in my ASP.NET MVC code?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a new MVC project which uses the entity framework. I'm spitting out messages (This is a bulletin board style section) now depending on some conditional factors the row in the table output must have a different class style.

The model that is passed to the page from the controller is the entity Model (Called Messages and contains the same fields as the database)

To get the row styles in, I did the following:

```
<%
   int i = 0;
   foreach (var message in ViewData.Model.MessageList)
   {
       string className = "rowEven";

       if (i % 2 == 0) { className = "rowOdd"; }
       if (message.Deleted) { className = "deleted"; }
       if (message.AuthorisedBy == null) { className = "notAuth"; }
       if (message.Deleted) { className = "deleted"; }
        
%>
<tr class="<%=className%>">
    <td><%= Html.CheckBox("mc1")%></td>
    <td>
        <%= Html.ActionLink(message.Title, "Details", new { id = message.MessageID })%>
    </td>
    <td>User Name Here</td>
    <td><%= Html.Encode(message.PublishDateTime.ToString())%></td>
</tr>          
<%
       i++;
   } 
%>
```

Which is pretty ugly, there must be a better way of doing this, any suggestions?

Comment: Just want to add that you can use both a ViewModel and HtmlHelper. Some stuff (transforming the data) belongs in the ViewModel, some stuff (selecting specific CSS classes) belongs in an HTML helper. You might even want to go so far as to have a partial which takes a single MessageItemViewModel and renders just one row - that helps when you start doing Ajax stuff.

Comment: We have a lot of Ajax to do pretty soon, so I like the sound of what you have said. Can you provide some links for referance or some examples? We are very new to MVC.

Comment: It would take some extra effort, but switching view engines might give you a clearer look of the page content. Take a look at Spark View Engine: http://sparkviewengine.com/

Comment: @Liam: You just go e.g. <% foreach (MessageListItemViewModel x in Model.MessageList) { Html.RenderPartial("MessageListItem", x); } %>. Then you make a partial view called "MessageListItem" which takes just one MessageListItemViewModel and renders only that row. Then you can e.g. make an action method which only returns that partial (and e.g. use jQuery to plonk that row on the page). You can wrap up all of your presentation layer logic inside your MessageListItemViewModel's constructor, or in HtmlHelpers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is most definitely presentation logic and a view is where it belongs. However, you'd better move that CSS class selection code to a view helper, which will accept both `Message` and `MessageList`:

```
public static string GetMessageCssClassName(this /* Don't remember :) */, Message message, MessageList messages)
{
    var cssClassName = messages.IndexOf(message) % 2  == 0 ?
        "rowOdd" : "rowEven";

    if(message.Deleted) cssClassName = "deleted";
    if(message.AuthorisedBy == null) cssClassName = "notAuth"; 
    if(message.Deleted) cssClassName = "deleted";
}
```

And now you can call that in your `<tr class="Html.GetMessageCssClassName(...)">`, getting rid of `i` counter:

```
<% foreach (var message in ViewData.Model.MessageList) { %>
    <tr class="<%= Html.GetMessageCssClassName(message, ViewData.Model.MessageList) %>">
        <td><%= Html.CheckBox("mc1")%></td>
        <td>
            <! -- Remaining stuff here -->
<% } %>
```

Comment: You extend GetMessageCssClassName(this HtmlHelper helper, :) Might also want to add a note where to add the extension method and how to incude namespaces.

Comment: It also gives you the option of adding unit tests to the parts of the  presentation layer which contain logic and would otherwise probably not get automated tests written around it, which can be a nice bonus.

Answer (score 2):

I would reccomend using model-view-viewmodel here. This allows you to encapsulate a lot of your logic in a view model class, you then just call methods on your view model rather than putting your logic inline. this would make it look something like this...

```
       <%  foreach (var messageViewModel in ViewData.Model.MessageList) { %>
                <tr class="<%=message.RowClass%>">
                    <td><%= Html.CheckBox("mc1")%></td>
                    <td>
                        <%= Html.ActionLink(message.Title, "Details", new { id = message.MessageID })%>
                    </td>
                    <td>User Name Here</td>
                    <td><%= Html.Encode(message.PublishedAt)%></td>
                </tr>                 
       <% } %>
```

While you end up with a lot more classes you get much more readable markup and your application is far more testable. It turns your view into a very simple window onto your view model. The view model then encapsulates any logic and properties that are needed solely by the view.

In response to your comment [here](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2009/06/29/how-we-do-mvc-view-models.aspx) is an article that addresses the model - view - view model pattern in MVC. You just need to create a class with a bunch of properties and/or methods and populate this class with everything you need. Then pass the class to your view instead of passing the model directly. You can even use AutoMapper or another mapping framework to automatically map your models to your view models.

Comment: Hi jack,

I like the idea of this, can you give furthor examples of how we can achieve this?

Comment: Updated the post to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

How about adding some helper methods? You can write your own extension methods to the base HtmlHelper class, so you could write something like:

```
...
<tr class="<%= Html.GetMessageCssClass(i, message) %>">
...
```

Answer (score 0):

As lots have already mentioned, you could just write an extension method for your `Message` class that sits inside your Namespace.Site project (the mvc project).

Something like:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string CssClass(this Message message,int counter)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            return "rowOdd";
        else if (message.AuthorisedBy == null) 
            return "notAuth";    
        else if (message.Deleted) 
            return "deleted";

        return "rowEven";
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<tr class="<%=message.CssClass(i)%>">
    <td><%= Html.CheckBox("mc1")%></td>
    <td><%= Html.ActionLink(message.Title, "Details", new { id = message.MessageID })%></td>
    <td>User Name Here</td>
    <td><%= Html.Encode(message.PublishDateTime.ToString())%></td>
</tr>
```